# Optional type in recursively defined class

Tags: c++

I'm making a tensor class that can make tensors of any order. For example a third order 3 by 2 by 4 float tensor is made using `Tensor<float, 3, 2, 4> a`. The elements are recursively stored as arrays of lower order tensors, until the 1st order, at which point they're stored as an array of the given type.

```
template <typename T, int m, int ...n>
class Tensor {
public:
    std::array<std::conditional<sizeof...(n) == 0, T, Tensor<T, n...>>, m> a;
};
```

I have a main loop to test it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    Tensor<float, 3, 2, 4> a;
    // Tensor<float, 3> b;
    std::cout << typeid(a.a[0]).name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, constructing `b` fails but `a` succeeds. Also `a.a[0]` should simply be of type `Tensor<float, 2, 4>`, but instead it's some conditional type, at runtime. How is this even possible? Don't understand what's going on here, both why `b` fails with `a` succeeding (seems impossible) and why the types are conditionals at runtime.

Comment: Where is `c` defined? I don't understand how `c.a[0]` is supposed to be anything in particular.

Comment: That was supposed to be a.a[0]; changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating `std::conditional<sizeof...(n) == 0, T, Tensor<T, n...>>` instantiates `Tensor<T, n...>` even when the condition is true, meaning you give the template one argument instead of the 2+ it requires. Lazy arguments don't exist in C++ for general use (including standard library templates). You need to delay the instantiation of the problematic template so that you instantiate it only when applicable. I find the easiest way to do that is with `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
static T type();

static auto determine_element_type() {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(n) == 0) {
        return type<T>();
    } else {
        return type<Tensor<T, n...>>();
    }
}

std::array<decltype(determine_element_type()), m> a;
```

Your type of `a` was off because you used the `std::conditional` type itself instead of `std::conditional_t` or `typename std::conditional<...>::type` to get the resulting type.

Answer (score 1):

`std::conditional` is a type trait. The way a type trait works, by convention, is that the result of the type-level computation is a member type alias of the `std::conditional` class, which otherwise is useless. I.e. `std::conditional` is basically defined like this:

```
template<bool, typename, typename>
struct conditional;
template<typename T, typename F>
struct conditional<true, T, F> { using type = T; };
template<typename T, typename F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { using type = F; };
```

There are also template aliases to reduce typing:

```
template<bool B, typename T, typename F>
using conditional_t = typename std::conditional<B, T, F>::type;
```

And you're meant to use it like this

```
template <typename T, int m, int ...n>
struct Tensor {
    std::array<std::conditional_t<sizeof...(n) == 0, T, Tensor<T, n...>>, m> a;
};
```

This doesn't actually work: if you try to instantiate `Tensor<float, 3>`, then that tries to instantiate `Tensor<float>`, and that fails, since `Tensor` must have at least one `int`. It doesn't matter that the use of `Tensor<float>` is under `std::conditional_t`. `std::conditional_t` is not like a `? :` conditional. It is like a function

```
Type conditional_t(bool b, Type t, Type f) { return b ? t : f; }
```

The "arguments" are evaluated before the conditional switches between them. If one of the arguments is ill-formed, the conditional will not save you.

A better design would be specialization of the whole class.

```
template<typename T, int... ns>
struct tensor;
// a rank-0 tensor is a scalar
template<typename T>
struct tensor<T> {
    T value;
};
// a rank-(n+1) tensor is some number of rank-n tensors
template<typename T, int n, int... ns>
struct tensor<T, n, ns...> {
    std::array<tensor<T, ns...>, n> value;
};
```

Not sure what you meant by `Tensor<float, 3, 2, 4>` working in your version; didn't work for me!

[Here's a neat, complete example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAA4ArKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiAtWADqgWE6rR6hibmvv6BdPaOLkbunt6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcamlskqanQZWQQxzm4eXlYKmdm5YQV1ZRVxCTUAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMDsiGWADU4iM6WcTMAJ6z2OIADACCo%2BOTmDNz6nXEmMxGqxvbWwSYRj7CN7M6BEs%2BWmf7ACqkU8wGRBctgYAqIpmhaHUAPovN4HAAiU0%2Bs1kW0uNzuD0wTxh7yMXx%2BDgIADoSVMIYDNscDKopjcISRkZcAPRM35TRa0ADWAFp1rStAoSFM8Ao2QoWMJiGjbvdmI85jjaB9ERSqTS6YKpXMkSNsDMAOwozZTE2IqYANzYBixIyNpv5GLlNuer1x%2BwAYhT7S01Mh%2BfTiFMqMRUEZIQ4sAAPDwQd1BzoGu3200nAh9WiJqgQTrifVwxlbe25/OF02fGaSABsEcwkezifZmDTxAzlsMNukBpLxrLYLodQr1e0tfr4IHuc7qfTFqtHa7l2LBc2LLZHJ5EFock4CY1QpFU0FeLJVUDqCo7JEPIzu%2BICmljvlLreSqP32F9DJBPoJKJZLvusuNUCH9TUnjfWgfghH9VkTS5vQIdAQBABZlmxAUGW1SCFGg3VIJgttrSXe10VlR9FWVT0ANLE0fTwP0byDEMwxraNiFjeNYOo5MpxbRjQ3DYdWOoH46kQkAjGYTlMAEm5gA8SElAAR2tWgBieQk8N1bMc1tODTUXLiSMxbFXRfD0vVNWj6PQrUdHArCcL1fBmGAdiqB%2Bcsx2AqRKwAL3hKZ1gTCc9OTRtmwzYN%2BJYmNxAsWQqziuEIEJYUfi86FXXU%2BgsNWH9hQUYLDVCsKUybacoDweFZgREVgsSqsph/YKRjjLM8ATEApl8ojSuLHSkxNAyexNcsfJYlKPzwdL%2BwITK3myghct1fK6obHjW1nOLpDwJKiQmkVmuRecuM82bBwOqaZohOacUW5bsFWwq%2Bxu9byt4gisXi3aLDhfbBJS7CSQGk6RqmHxiDwS0bhAEqjKdEznwor9iVJABJf81i4qyQKFKLmMEmM4x89yDwQpDCUwOTiAUzBlK0NTDhyqYMccorBu496MxC4rDRvMCHJJVYkPxgSo1i%2BKfKSiAMrupmlr/PLSTWkKuNK8LpyzDGCSBokBpKos806aC80XU3dK44bFwtq5NnhsjTOVN9Uog99Ud/CEUfyoxMelAMBb/H8fh9xypnQVACAgfnMM/QOhd1F7xyrSMfmjuzIOD3WYK8wclnZkqNtx2zwN1zPHJFpixdrCWEsraXZay%2BWHqe66oTlnQNKmH2ld/PhntVsH7XLBRjAC9ZerCmg2NSqqasC47Z7mMkF7kOQExHowK1kEYEUjf6oxSnXmqmAAqKYln3kdpqmPujpt9XC43ieu311FTdRLZUokhx6wH4ibKeFQVgqA5Q/F4FMbgMEmzMACmnIBICFbgMgbqJCzlXLbWljPdmGteKLzjNyTgUwuqcGOv1Z%2BcDgGgIgfhVIPNZCGkkD8TgPx1gsLNvmc2HNRJITQP8A4OgnhhwjhAcOkdoE/HNKkboFopFEk%2BvwwRUhJBxR0JuSQyibbFkGN0VgIBBgWEGKQUwgx1iGNQHogRMg5AHl6P0fYoxOCGIIHo0xnRuici8GYIkABOSQ%2BpJAWG8SMSsZhOBhMrN4oQejuCGOMaY0g5jBiGIUCAVhziTHaNIHAWASBq7IH%2BCQcglAsjAAUAABREMoBgCBUAAHdjGONIGgO4eAHhBAqY4Vg1S6lxMMc0nwrTqgTBEMAMJ6xWH9MGcQAA8v8bp9SXGGLyZsYgpS9FLOjMgDI%2BBjGGJoPQJgbAOA8H4IIYQogUCrxkEIPArgUmQG6KgHwxQIR6O5KJGqEgrEyEkPEwUfQBiCFEg4DpVSakLMGI4nReiDFGMWQkvRkYzCVm5JWbgYJznACmGEok6xcVTGwJsgpgYIC4EIEKBxCZLEJWkE4xZbjSAeO4JwXF/j9TcHWJWEYnAzC8pGIw3RgwYlwoyQipJihUmkHSa46FgxJCxPhYkulGSGWSNvEEEA3AgA)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the tensor as nested arrays like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    template <class T, std::size_t n, std::size_t... ns>
    auto helper() {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(ns) == 0)
            return std::array<T, n>();
        else
            return std::array<decltype(helper<T, ns...>()), n>();
    }
}

template <class T, std::size_t n, std::size_t... ns>
using Tensor = decltype(detail::helper<T, n, ns...>());
    
int main()
{
    Tensor<float, 2, 3, 4> b;
    b[0][1][2] = 1;
}
```